# indexing error in list in python

Tags: python

```
B=l.append((l[i]+A+B))
```

l is a list here and i am trying to append into it more value for it to act as an array . But its still giving me error like list index out of range  . How to get rid of it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many problems in your code:

1) the `append` method **does not return anything**, so it does not make sense to write `B = l.append(...)`

2) The double parenthesis are confusing, the code you wrote is exactly equivalent to `B.append(l[i]+A+B)`

3) Finally, obviously, the index `i` must be a valid index for the list `l`, otherwise you will get an `IndexError` exception.

Answer (score 1):

List index out of range means that `i` is greater than `len(l) - 1` (since Python, and many other programming languages, use indexing that starts at 0 instead of 1, the last item in the list has index `len(l) - 1`, not just `len(l)`.

Try debugging like so:

```
try:
    B = l.append((l[i] + A + B))
except IndexError:
    print "Appending from index", i, "to list l of length:", len(l)
    raise
```

This will tell you the value of `i` and the length of `l` when the append fails so you can search for the problem.

Is this in a loop? It may help to show us the code of the loop. It could be that, even though you're increasing the length of `l` by appending to it, you're increasing `i` even faster, so that it eventually gets to be bigger than `len(l) - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Variable `i` is larger or equal to the size of the `l` array.