# python lists error

Tags: python

```
A=s.append(s[i]+A+B)
```

A=s.append(s[i]+A+B)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'long' and 'str'

What does this error mean ? A and B are strings and s is a list

Comment: Clearly related to your earlier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612461/indexing-error-in-list-in-python

Consider editing the original instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`s` may be a list, but the element - `s[i]` - is *not* - it's a long, as indicated by the error.

In addition, `append()` operates on the list directly - it returns `None`, so you're actually setting `A` to be None - probably not what you wanted!

There are two things you can do to help avoid this type of error in the future.

1. Don't use one-letter variable names. Use descriptive, one to three-word length names that describe *what* the variable has in it (and/or what it's supposed to be used for).
2. When you do have a problem, try putting it in a try/except block where you put the error name after `except` and print out the offending variables:

> 

```
try:
    s.append(s[i]+A+B)
except TypeError:
    print "Failed to add", s[i], ",", A, ",", "and", B
    raise
```

Don't forget the `raise` at the end there - that way you don't just ignore the issue and start getting really strange errors.

Answer (score 0):

If A and B are strings, then s[i] must be a 'long'.

Answer (score 0):

s[i] is likely a long. You can't add a long to a string.

Try:

> A=s.append(str(s[i])+A+B)